# How to return array of a class in Java

Tags: java, oop, wrapper

I am trying to wrap `TestClass1[]` in `TestClass` and for this I have created a `TestClass`. There is a method in another class `FunctionClass` which will return the array of the `TestClass`. I have defined some variables in `Testclass` one is `String` and the other one is a class `TestClass2`. I will wrap the `TestClass2` in `Testclass`.

`Testclass2` also has 2 variables, one is `String` and one is `int`. I want to know how can i construct an array of `Testclass` which should have the corresponding variables in it.

I have the following code.

```
public class Testclass {

private String attrName;
    private TestClass1 tc;
    private TestClass2 tc2;

Testclass(Testclass1[] tc1){

    for(int i=0; i<tc1.length; i++){
    tc = tc1[i];
    attrName = this.tc.name; 
    tc2 = new TestClass2 (this.tc.elements); //this.tc.elements will return an Array of SomeClass which is not implemented by me.
    }

}

/**
 * Returns the Name.
 */
public String getName()
{
    return attrName;
}

/**
 * Returns the Testclass2 Array
 */
public TestClass2[] getTestClass2(){

//What to do ??
}



 /**
 * Testclass2 which is inner class of TesTClass.
 */
 private class Testclass2 {

    private int value;
    private string attribute;
    private SomeClass some;

    TestClass2 (SomeClass[] someClass){

        for(int i=0; i<someClass.length; i++){
        some= someClass[i]; 
        this.value= some.value;
                    this.attributes = some.attribute;

        }
    }

            /**
             * Returns the Value.
             */
    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

            /**
             * Returns the Attribute.
             */
            public string getAttribute(){
        return attribute;
    }
```

Method in `Function` class is as follows:

```
public Testclass[] getTestClass(){

 //What to do?

}
```

Comment: Either your nickname, or your question seems to be out-of-place... Please clarify your question... It is not very easy to tell what you would like to know, and without that, it's really tough to try to answer it correctly...

Comment: `new tc2 ` - That would not even compile. What exactly do you want, is not clear from your question. Please try to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry I am beginner in development. And sorry Rohit it was my mistake i wrote tc2 accidently. I have changed the tc2 to TestClass2. Rohit Where do i need to be more specific? I dont know what to write more :( @ppeterka I just want to build and return array of TestClass in getTestClass().

Comment: @JavaDeveloper, you want to return an array of `TestClass2` or `TestClass`? And man, you really need to be more specific in your problem, you need to give us an isolated problem to work with, a clearer question.

Comment: We don't care about your hole code lines, just be specific why can't you just create the array you want to??

Comment: @HericDenis I want to get TestClass2[] in TestClass and TestClass[] in FunctionClass method getTestclass2(). I dont know what you guys need to know more. TestClass constructor is taking TestClass1[] as an argument. TestClass1[] is an array of TestClass1 and Testclass1 has 2 variables. One is String variable and the other one is an array of SomeClass. TestClass2 constructor will take this SomeClass[] as an argument. SomeClass has 2 variables one is String and the second is int. I dont know what and how to explain more :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make attributes of the class `TestClass` be arrays. Create *getters* and setters if necessary. Create constructor *initializer* that accepts values or `TestClass1` and initializes `TestClass2` array. Create default constructor for `TestClass2`.

```
TestClass(TestClass1[] tc1, String attrName){

    tc = tc1;
    this.attrName = attrName; 
    if (tc != null) {
      tc2 = new TestClass2[tc.length];
      for(int i = 0; i< tc.length; i++) {
        TestClass2 t2c = new TestClass2(tc[i].getElements()); //this.tc.elements will   return an Array of SomeClass which is not implemented by me.
        tc2[i] = t2c;
      }
   }
}

/**
 * Returns the Testclass2 Array
 */
public TestClass2[] getTestClass2(){

  //What to do ?? 
  return tc2;
}

class TestClass2 {
   /**
    * Default constructor
    */ 
   TestClass2(){}
```

Comment: thanks alot for your answer. You have understood my problem i think. Could you please go through my question and my comments again because I have re written it and please try to answer it again.

Answer (score 0):

I find your constructor weird. Does you code even compile? You want to assign an array to tc2, but you didn't choose it as an array type. Use this then:

```
private TestClass2[] tc2;
```

Then in getTestClass2, just do:

```
return tc2;
```